# How to create a relationship between 2 nodes where the nodes' labels, properties and the relationship are variable using APOC

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I'm having a really hard time querying Neo4j with Cypher and the APOC library. I've been recommended to use the APOC library a few days ago to create nodes with a label based on a variable. Creating these nodes works great, but a few days have past since and I still can't figure out how to create a relationship between these nodes.

The error messages I'm getting are the same as the ones I got before I started using APOC. The first character of the query is always seen as invalid input. Another one I have been getting is that the procedure call does not provide the required number of arguments.

I don't really understand the APOC documentation on how to create a relationship. I also tried CALL APOC.help('relationship') and saw that it's also possible to use apoc.merge. This can't be found in their documentation though. Furthermore I read about APOC's new summer release on Neo4J's blog, but I still really don't know how I can make this query work.

I've tried every possible tweak for the query I could think of, but the nodes just won't connect. I clearly don't know what I'm doing and missing out on something.

I really would like to be able to match 2 nodes and create a relationship between them. These nodes' labels and properties are variable since that's the way they were created. If possible, it would be great if the relationship type could be based on a variable too.

I'm working with NodeJS, the Neo4j driver and put the APOC Jar file succesfully in Neo4j's plugin folder.

Here's one of the failed queries to get an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
('CALL apoc.create.relationship([{labelParamN1}], {name: {nameParamN1}}, {relationParam}, [{labelParamN2}], {name: {nameParamN2}})',
{labelParamN1: labelParamN1, nameParamN1: nameParamN1, labelParamN2: labelParamN2, nameParamN2: nameParamN2, relationParam: relation})
```

Some help with this query would be really appreciated

Comment: 1. What is your error message? If I try your query, I get an error `Procedure call does not provide the required number of arguments: got 5 expected 4.` The error message details the required parameters: `apoc.create.relationship(from :: NODE?, relType :: STRING?, props :: MAP?, to :: NODE?)`.
2. When encountering sporadically documented libs, it's often best to check its [the related unit tests](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.2/src/test/java/apoc/create/CreateTest.java#L125), which provides an example of how it should be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me the related unit tests. I didn't see them before. I'll defenitly check them first if I get stuck again in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to use `MATCH` to get the required nodes (`n1` and `n2`), and then use the `apoc.create.relationship` method. Provided that you do want to add any properties on the relationships (and so you just pass `{}` for the third parameter), the following query should work:

```
MATCH (n1 {name: {nameParamN1}}), (n2 {name: {nameParamN2}})
CALL apoc.create.relationship(n1, {relationParam}, {}, n2)
YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! It works. I checked if, besides name, I could add more properties to n1 and n2. That's working great too. I can finally continue again! I don't know why I kept trying to match the nodes by label, that isn't neccesary at all. Thanks for your effort!